# nested router is not working code spliitting

Tags: reactjs, react-router, code-splitting

my project structure is    app
                            |
                         router(rocket)
                            |     |
                        calendar    badge

app.js

```
const HomeComponent = lazy(() => import('./Home'));
const RocketComponent = lazy(() => import('./RocketComponent'));



ReactDOM.render(
    <HashRouter>
                <div className="app">
                    <div className="container">
                        <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
                            <Route exact path="/" render={(props) => <HomeComponent {...props} />}/>
                            <Route path="/rocket" render={(props) => <RocketComponent {...props}/>}/>
                        </Suspense>
                    </div>
                </div>
    </HashRouter>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

RocketComponent.js

```
import HeaderNew from "./HeaderNew";
import React, {lazy} from 'react';
import RocketMenuNew from "./RocketMenuNew";
import {Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom";

const BadgeComponent = lazy(() => import('./Documents/badge/Document'));
const CalendarComponent = lazy(() => import('./Documents/calendar/Document'));

class RocketComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="documents-new">
                <HeaderNew />
                <RocketMenuNew />
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path={`${this.props.match.path}`} render={(props) => <BadgeComponent {...props} />}/>
                        <Route path={`${this.props.match.path}/badge`}  render={(props) => <CalendarComponent {...props} />}/>
                    </Switch>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default RocketComponent
```

localhost:3000/#/rocket is working and code splitting is well.
but localhost:3000/#/rocket/calendar is not working code splitting
how to nested router code splitting??

Comment: pretty sure it is not hitting the switch in RocketComponent what I would recommend is moving all your routes to app.js, use a variable which stores all your route update it conditionally depending upon your current URL.